# Waiting till my background network request arrives in selenium python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I am trying to make the driver wait till I fetch my dedicated network req after a page load. But it is not working as expected.

```
url = validatior.Validation.valid_url(nput("Please enter the website url : "))
driver.get(url)
link = driver.current_url
requests = driver.wait_for_request("/b/ss/", 30)
```

Above is the code snippet I am using.

I want to fetch all the network calls contains the "b/ss" string in the header

Comment: When you say `contains the "b/ss" string in the header` do you mean the url contains that?

Comment: Yes, anyway, I got this piece working.